# RestClient is not returning exact unmarshalled object when Generics are used

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jaxb

I am making RESTful WS call like shown below:

```
ResponseEntity<ResponseHolder> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, ResponseHolder.class, 300788);
```

But, when on return I check value inside responseEntity, it is ElementNsImpl object instead of Employee object which I am embedding into ResponseHolder.
So, the condition `(responseEntity.getBody().getResponse() instanceof Employee)` is evaluatinng to false!

---

Below is my server side controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{empId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseHolder getEmployee(@PathVariable int empId) {
        System.out.println("Returning employee details for empId = " + empId);
        Employee employee = new Employee(123, "Akshay", "A", "Technology", 500000);

        ResponseHolder<Employee> responseHolder = new ResponseHolder<Employee>(employee, null);

        return responseHolder;
    }
```

Below is the code from my `ResponseHolder.java` class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlSeeAlso(Employee.class)
public class ResponseHolder<T> {

    private T response;
    private ErrorStatus errorStatus;

    public ResponseHolder() {
    }

    public ResponseHolder(T response, ErrorStatus errorStatus) {
        this.response = response;
        this.errorStatus = errorStatus;
    }

    public T getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    public void setResponse(T response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public ErrorStatus getErrorStatus() {
        return errorStatus;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setErrorStatus(ErrorStatus errorStatus) {
        this.errorStatus = errorStatus;
    }
}
```

What exactly I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody any help please? I am stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not an Employee but a serialization of your Employee (a String). You have to reensamble the data in the client side and then fill an employee object.

Comment: OK. But why Spring RestClient is not doing that for me?
RestClient perfectly works if I do not use Generics in class ResponseHolder.
Is there any more JAXB related annotation I need to configure to make Spring RestClient understand what it is receiving?